# Default/suggested familiar names for Mite, Tumbelemur and Seed Sprite

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

When you get a new familiar and are prompted to name them, there are four default suggested names which can be cycled through by pressing triangle.

e.g. when you get Mite, the initially suggested name is "Mitey", then if you press triangle you get another suggestion "Matey" then "Mito" then a fourth option then it cycles back to "Mitey" e.t.c.

What are the four default suggested names for Mite, Tumbelemur and Seed Sprite?

I know this is a bit of a strange question to ask, so thanks in advance for anyone who takes the time to answer!

Comment: Did you already test these yourself in-game...?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you asking? What are you going to do with this info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggested names are:

- **Mite:** Mitey, Matey, Mito, Smitey
- **Thumbelemur:** Lemahl, Thumbo, Curly, Angelemur
- **Seed Sprite:** Sid, Sayeed, Planter, Seymour